# MySQL linear MIN MAX interpolation value extraction

Tags: mysql, interpolation

I want to do interpolation with BASh script. I have a data base which [from a snippet] looks like this:

[image]

For a given value *`timestamp`* I want the SQL to return the nearest greater value of *`timestamp`*  with corresponding `value` and similarily for the nearest lesser value of *`timestamp`* also returning the corresponding the `value`.

**Q:** What would the query look like to extract this information?

Comment: If you found a better solution please share because i know mine isn't very optimized (2 selects in select clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Also note that timestamp is a [reserved word for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

```
SELECT (
    SELECT `timestamp` 
    FROM your_table 
    WHERE `timestamp` > 'your_value' 
    ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC 
    LIMIT 1
) AS one_greater,
(
    SELECT `timestamp` 
    FROM your_table 
    WHERE `timestamp` < 'your_value' 
    ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) AS one_less;
```

Comment: I've broken down the two selects, to two independent queries - as I need these two variables to do an interpolation.

Currently the `'one_less'` query returns `'NULL'` value - so I am trouble shooting that.

Comment: I 've checked it and it works fine. It returns one row of two columns.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data using SQL Fiddle to check your query?

Comment: My time stamp format was incorrect - thus the null result. But your method worked - Thanks!